# RDO Openstack allinone to add one mor compute node

Tags: cloud, openstack, openstack-nova

I have install RDO `Openstack` using `--allinone` on CentOS6 using nova-network using FlatDHCPManager. Now i am trying to add new compute node in cluster but i am confused, Document saying on compute node you only need `nova-compute` daemon.

- But i am confused how it will configure network br100 for networking without `nova-network` daemon? How controller assign DHCP to VM etc?
- Also do i need to copy `nova.conf` from controller to new compute node?
- Any advice welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is 
Here's the key to FlatDHCPManager configuration in `/etc/nova/nova.conf` for multiple nova compute node:

```
flat_interface=eth0
flat_network_bridge=br100
```

you should configure the network bridge on new compute node via `nova-network` (preferred) or do it manually on your own.

- it is the dnsmasq daemon (started by service `openstack-nova-network`) listens to `br100` device that assigns ip configs to VMs over DHCP. there is a dnsmasq daemon on each nova compute node. Notice that you need to manually kill the dnsmasq daemon process when changing network configuration.
- `nova.conf` is shared by both controller and compute. and you can copy it to your new compute nodes. notice that you need to change specific entries which differ from host to host including: `my_ip`, `vncserver_listen` and `vncserver_proxyclient_address`.

Here's a good [guide](http://www.mirantis.com/blog/openstack-networking-flatmanager-and-flatdhcpmanager/) to show how FlatDHCPManager works.

Comment: Thanks for reply! also i have put few more entries for `multi_host=true` so all node has own networking instead of forward traffic to controller.